# How to avoid bad performance when calling a library that uses OpenMP

Tags: c, performance, openmp

I'm calling a dynamically linked [libdivsufsort](https://github.com/y-256/libdivsufsort) in a loop, each iteration for a different piece of data and with a separate output. Only a few kbytes of data are processed each iteration (I can't change that). However, the performance I get is often abysmal.

I discovered that if I call the right combination of functions over the output of divsufsort, my whole program runs up to 10x *FASTER* than if I do nothing except the divsufsort call. That varies with the gcc optimization options. I'm afraid that I can't provide any reasonable minimal working example short of my entire program, given the chaos-like nature that it appears to have...

Profiling the program, I discovered that when it runs slower, 50% of the time is spent in `gomp_barrier_wait_end`, and other 40% of the time in `gomp_team_barrier_wait_end`, and less than 10% of the time actually doing useful work. Apparently divsufsort uses OpenMP (I never used it), and that is likely the cause of the slowdowns.

So, what can in my end do to aways avoid that gomp barriers overhead?

Comment: Simply disable OpenMP by setting the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable to 1. Spending too much time in barriers usually mean poorly balanced work distribution or a problem that is generally unsuited for OpenMP parallelisation.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, calling my program with  `env OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` before it seems to solve the slowdown. I tried to use `setenv()` and `putenv()` in C to replicate that w/o having to mess with the shell, but no luck. Any idea what I can do in C to disable the threads of something I call? The threads in libdivsufsort probably work better when processing megabytes of data a time, but I dunno.

Comment: Include `<omp.h>`, put in your code `omp_set_num_threads(1);` **before** the call to libdivsufsort, then compile and link with `-fopenmp`.